# How can I cast a number to hours?

Tags: excel

I want to calculate the difference between

1. the hours someone has worked in a month and (E34 = 194:00)
2. the hours someone must work at minimum in a month (E35)

E36 is equal to 23 formatted as d(ays).

Now I calculate the E35 as following:
= E36 * 8
If I format it as 'General', I get 184.
Now I want to cast this 184 to hours as 184:00, so I can do E34-E35 to get the 10 hours.

How can I achieve that?

I tried to use following formats for 184 in E36:

- hh:mm --> I get 00:00
- [hh]:mm --> I get 4416
- [h]:mm;@ --> I get 4416

How I see, it's multiplying 184 with 24 and recognizing 184 as days instead of hours.

Comment: When it comes to time `1` is one day or 24 hours, `0.041667` is 1 hour. So take 184, divide by 24 and format as `[hh]:mm`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: write it please as answer that i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to time `1` is one day or 24 hours, `0.041667` (`1/24`) is 1 hour. So take `184`, divide by `24` and format as `[hh]:mm`